# Can't log in to Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

yesterday it asked for my pin and I think I gave it my personal pin instead of my work pin number and today every time I go to log on to my work gmail it says "Can't reach this page."  Every two months or so, gmail locks me out of my gmail.  It is probably something I am doing but I don't know what?  Then I will get back on one day and it miraculously reappears.  It wouldn't be a problem as I can access it on my phone, however, my boss wants to do conference calls and Zoom and I can't do them with my phone!  Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the "Can't reach this page", the most straight forward solution is to clear the  cookies and delete the cache of your web browser. Then sign in again to your account.

Regarding being lock out from time to time, for security reasons, Google will ask to sign-in again in the web browser every certain time.